# Camel-FTP timing out and creating 0 byte files

Tags: java, servlets, ftp, apache-camel

I'm working on a servlet where we have an FTP URI stored in a DB.. users will select an FTP URI (by a "friendly" name), and then upload a file to it from the site. I want to use Camel to do the actual uploading since the URIs we're storing were previously used in camel endpoints.

Here's the code that's sending the message with the file:

```
public void uploadValidFiles(List<ValidatedFile> files, UploadLocationInfo info)
{
    final String uri = info.getUri();
    RouteBuilder rb = new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("direct:start").to(uri);
        }
    };

    CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();

    try {
        ctx.addRoutes(rb);
        ctx.start();
        ProducerTemplate prod = new DefaultProducerTemplate(ctx);
        prod.start();
        for(ValidatedFile file : files)
        {
            File temp = File.createTempFile(file.getFilename(), ".tmp");
            //Transfer MultiPartFile to File
            file.getFile().transferTo(temp);
            prod.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:start", temp, "CamelFileName", file.getFilename());
        }
        prod.stop();
        ctx.stop();
    }
    catch (CamelExecutionException ce)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem!");
        throw new RuntimeException(ce);
    }
}
```

The URI I'm testing with is: `ftp://user@ftp.domain.com/folder?password=s3cr3t`

On the site I'm choosing the URI and the File, I hit Upload... and then it just hangs. Eventually I get an HTTP500 with the text:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: [Body is file based: PATH\FILE.tmp]]

In my servlet's log I see:

> org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.

There IS a file being created on the FTP with the name of the uploaded file but it's size is 0

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by adding passiveMode=true and binary=true to the FTP URI